# How do I add the customer quick access bar to top of site?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, access

I have two sites, one of which has the customer quick access bar (shown below) showing on all pages, the other doesn't have this and I can't find it in the settings on the magento dashboard so assume I will have to edit a .phtml file?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious issue would be that:

1. The second theme is missing the following from `app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`:

   ```
   echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks')
   ```

Adding it will in turn add the relevant information from the instantiated `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` class.

Here you can see the default positioning (line 40):

Github: [magento-mirror/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml)

Other than that, you can also:

2. Ensure that `app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/page.xml` doesn't deviate from the native Magento file (or at least contains the essentials, you can use a text-comparison application like https://text-compare.com/)
3. Ensure that `app/design/frontend/theme/default/page/html/top.links.phtml` is properly in place.

Comment: Hi, the original header.phtml file contains this line of code. I also tried replacing the header.phtml file with the one in the link but this didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Edited the answer to include 2 additional points of reference worth looking into.